# Java send event automatically on setter

Tags: java, events, design-patterns, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am building an Java App, with Eclipse RCP.
When my model classes are modified (thanks to my setter methods) I would like to send events (IEventBroker) corresponding to each differents setters, that my differents UI elements can catch. I thought about this pattern :

```
Model {
    setValueForA() {...}
    setValueForB() {...}
    setValueForC() {...}
}

ServiceLayer {
    setValueForA() {
        model.setValueForA();
        sendEventAUpdated();
    }
    setValueForB() {
        model.setValueForB();
        sendEventBUpdated();
    }
    setValueForC() {
        model.setValueForC();
        sendEventCUpdated();
    }
}
```

Is there a way with a framework, library, annotations,... whatever who can helps me to implement less code, and to avoid this copying code? I am on 1.8 JDK

Comment: In my humble opinion, you don't want annotations doing this.  Code should be straightforward and easy to understand.  It should not have obscured, "secret" functionality.  For what it's worth, [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) is designed to assist with firing property change events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a candidate for [Observer pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) Java language provides some basic support through `Observable` and `Observer` classes. The downside is that you will have to **extend** these in your corresponding classes. This frees you from the overhead of adding observer/obervable code though. Broadly, you just add notify code in your `setter` methods of model object. Define Observers, then tie them together from application(Service) code. Whenever a `set` happens, if it has notify coded, it will notify all observers associated with the model object.

Following is a rough example based on code in question :

```
Model extends Observable {  //various observers can be notified when property changes.
    setValueForA(Object value) {...
      setChanged();
      notifyObservers(value);
    }
    //Example setter above. Similar code needed in all required properties.
}
```

Now create observers

```
public class SomePropertyObserver implements Observer
{
   private ObservableValue ov = null;
   public SomePropertyObserver(ObservableValue ov)
   {
      this.ov = ov;
   }

   //This method is called whenever the observed object is changed.
   public void update(Observable obs, Object obj)
   {
      //obj is the value sent from notifyObservers called from observable
   }
}
```

Tie them together in your application code :

```
Model model = new Model();
SomePropertyObserver observer = new SomePropertyObserver(model);
model.addObserver(observer); // now observer will get notification whenever a property changes in model.
```

There are some downsides, as you have to extend `Observable` and hence you are very tightly coupled and restricted of further object extension.